# Android Studio delete line and duplicate line shortcuts

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the shortcut in Android Studio to delete a line? And what is the shortcut to duplicate a line?

*I found the answer in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html) and I am posting it below for quick reference.*

Answer (score 116, accepted):

### Linux/Windows

- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> : Duplicate current line or selection
- <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> : Delete current line

*Note from comments: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> cuts the current line.*

### Mac

- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> : Duplicate current line or selection
- <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd> : Delete current line

### See also

- [Android Studio Keyboard Shortcuts documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html)
- [Android Studio Shortcuts You Need the Most](http://javapapers.com/android/android-studio-shortcuts-you-need-the-most/)

If it's not working, check the Keymap settings:

[image]

Comment: Shift+Del cuts the current line, which of course isn't quite the same, but I find easier to remember than Ctrl+Y.

Comment: For some reason, this is not working in the new Android Studio

Comment: I found the issue. I was using the wrong Keymap in my Settings. Thanks @Suragch

Comment: Keymap : macOS is the one that fixed for me

Comment: Command+Y in mac works for me

Comment: this is gold! thanks! i couldn't figure out why command delete was not working anymore on my mac after updating Android studio

Answer (score 0):

On **Mac OS 11.3.1** and above just :

delete line completely :

```
Command + delete
```

and duplicate line :

```
command + d
```