# Is there shortcut to copy and delete line in one action in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

If i don't mistake there is a shortcut to copy deleted line in `Sublime Text 3`. Does `Android Studio` have such one?

Comment: Yes, here is link to a similar question as yours. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718193/android-studio-delete-line-and-duplicate-line-shortcuts

Comment: I have seen it. But i need copy, not duplicate, delete line after, and do it in one shortcut. If this is possible, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that: `Ctrl + X` without selecting